# Passing sort_by an array of sort fields

Tags: ruby, proc

If I have a array of hashes

```
collection = [
  { first_name: 'john', last_name: 'smith', middle: 'c'},
  { first_name: 'john', last_name: 'foo', middle: 'a'}
]
```

And an array of keys I want to sort by:

```
sort_keys = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

How can I pass these keys to `sort_by` given that the keys will always match the keys in the collection?

I've tried

```
collection.sort_by { |v| sort_keys.map(&:v) }
```

but this doesn't work. I believe I'll need to use a proc but I'm not sure how to implement it. Would appreciate any help!

Using Ruby 2.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change your `sort_keys` to contain symbols:

```
sort_keys = [:first_name, :last_name]
```

You can use [`values_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to retrieve the values:

```
collection.sort_by { |h| h.values_at(*sort_keys) }
#=> [{:first_name=>"john", :last_name=>"foo", :middle=>"a"}, {:first_name=>"john", :last_name=>"smith", :middle=>"c"}]
```

The array that is used to sort the hashes looks like this:

```
collection.map { |h| h.values_at(*sort_keys) }
#=> [["john", "smith"], ["john", "foo"]]
```

Comment: This works, thanks!! What is `values_at` doing behind the scenes?

It works without converting the keys to symbols, I believe because it's indifferent access.

Comment: No, he changed the keys in the `sort_keys` arrays to be symbols.  There is no indifferent access on a plain Ruby hash.